# Why isn't FFmpeg compiler-optimized?

Tags: gcc, ffmpeg

FFmpeg is compiled by first creating a debug build and then stripping debug symbols off.

```
LD      ffmpeg_g
CP      ffmpeg
STRIP   ffmpeg
```

Why not have compiler optimizations, `O3` for instance?

Comment: Nothing breaks, but the point is to figure the reasoning behind setting the default the way it is. While the optimized build runs correctly, I don't have a benchmark setup to comment on any speedup

Comment: Benchmark them. Speculating is one thing, but raw numbers are more tangible. If there is no performance boost, why bother using `-O3`?

Comment: My guess is that the "debug build" was actually an optimized build with debug information enabled. Yes, you can do this, and if you get a crash it's somewhat useful, but it's hell to debug since half the variables have been optimized away, and nothing runs in the order you'd expect. Actually, most system libraries on Linux systems are built this way (just in case), although the debug info is usually stored in separate files that are only optionally installed.

Comment: @Blender: Pretty obvious nobody is speculating anything - not sure how you got that feeling. Quite the contrary, the point of the post is to share & learn if there is already some kind of benchmark or any other justification. The sample size of the videos I have with me is not good enough to draw any conclusion. Besides, there might be other reasons other than performance: maybe os/compiler-compatibility, in which case benchmarking would be a waste of time

Answer (score 1):

The actual compiler flags aren't specified at link time, just compile time (previous to this), so chances are that it's actually compiled with -O2 or its like.  As mentioned in one of the other comments, it's also (by default) compiled with debug symbols (which are a separate issue from optimization flags), so it keeps these in ffmpeg_g and strips them from ffmpeg, for a smaller executable (should you want that).  Anyway you can see the compiler flags better if you run it like "make V=1" (may need to run a make clean first). HTH.